# hive doesn't support merge function

Tags: hive, hiveql, cloudera-manager

trying to update the value from table to another table, both of these tables have the same field name but different values, the query must be work fine on any normal DB but here it returns

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0
>   cannot recognize input near 'MERGE' 'INTO' 'FINAL'

```
MERGE 
INTO FINAL 
USING FIRST_STAGE
ON IMSI = FIRST_STAGE.IMSI and Site = FIRST_STAGE.Site
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  Min_Date = least(FIRST_STAGE.Min_Date, Min_Date),
  Max_Date = greatest(FIRST_STAGE.Max_Date, Max_Date),
  NoofDays = FIRST_STAGE.NoofDays + NoofDays,
  Down_Link = FIRST_STAGE.Down_Link + Down_Link,
  up_Link = FIRST_STAGE.up_Link + up_Link,
  connection = FIRST_STAGE.connection + connection
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( Min_Date, 
  Max_Date, 
  NoofDays, 
  IMSI, 
  Site, 
  Down_Link, 
  Up_Link, 
  Connection )
VALUES ( FIRST_STAGE.Min_Date, 
  FIRST_STAGE.Max_Date, 
  FIRST_STAGE.NoofDays, 
  FIRST_STAGE.IMSI, 
  FIRST_STAGE.Site, 
  FIRST_STAGE.Down_Link, 
  FIRST_STAGE.Up_Link, 
  FIRST_STAGE.Connection )
```

Comment: 1st thing hive isn't database. You can load data using HDFS files or using insert overwrite command/syntax

Comment: does impala support like these functions ?

Comment: I have made JDBC connection between pyspark and vettica and I accessed the needed data and the data has been transferred  to hive but now it I'm truing to update data  with each batch , any advice ?

Comment: you can do using beeline commands or  using GCP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive ***merge statement*** is introduced in [**`Hortonworks distribution`**](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_data-access/content/new-feature-insert-values-update-delete.html).

- Prerequisite for these `merge statement` to run is:

  Final table needs to be created with **`transactional enabled ,ORC format ,and bucketed`**.

AFAIK In case of [**`Cloudera distribution`**](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-10-x/topics/impala_upsert.html) we need to use **`Kudu`** to perform upsert operations starting from `cloudera-5.10+`.

**Note:** **`Upsert statement only works for Impala tables that use the Kudu storage engine.`**

- I don't think we can run merge statements as mentioned in the post in `CDH` distributions as of now.